# How to rig TARS from Interstellar?

Tags: rigging

From what I understand, this should be *extremely easy* to rig. The problem is I've never rigged anything, so I have no clue what I'm doing. I created this model, and I want to rig it where the origin points are. So that the outtermost legs are connected with the innermost legs at the top of the model, and the two center legs are connected at the bottom.
[image]

Comment: It seems as if searching for some simple rigging tutorials would be a better option than asking aquestion here.

Comment: Agree, it also seems that [TARS doesn't use a single fixed pivot](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=tars) at all for all its parts, they seem dynamic according to its needs

Comment: You could chain empties and use contraints if the model is made in pieces.